# Why can't GCC cross compiler find all libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

Why does it look for `libgcc` in the library search paths, but not for the `crt*.o` libraries (scroll down in the second code block below)? Also, why is it looking in `/lib` and `/usr/lib` under the sysroot, but not in `/tmptools/lib` under the sysroot (which is the only path that I actually want it to look in)? This is how the cross compiler was configured:

```
../binutils-2.26/configure --prefix="$LFS_CROSSTOOLCHAIN" --build=$LFS_BUILD_ARCH --host=$LFS_BUILD_ARCH --target=$LFS_TARGET_ARCH --with-lib-path="/tmptools/lib" --disable-multilib --disable-multiarch --disable-rpath --disable-nls --with-sysroot="$LFS_SYSROOT"
../gcc-6.1.0/configure --prefix="$LFS_CROSSTOOLCHAIN" --build=$LFS_BUILD_ARCH --host=$LFS_BUILD_ARCH --target=$LFS_TARGET_ARCH --disable-bootstrap --with-newlib --without-headers --with-local-prefix="/tmptools" --with-native-system-header-dir="/tmptools/include" --with-lib-path="/tmptools/lib" --disable-multilib --disable-multiarch --disable-rpath --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-nls --with-sysroot="$LFS_SYSROOT"
```

Where `LFS_CROSSTOOLCHAIN=/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools` and `LFS_SYSROOT=/home/main/lfs/3/root`.

This is example output:

```
$ 3/crosstools/bin/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -print-sysroot
/home/main/lfs/3/root
$ 3/crosstools/bin/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ld -print-sysroot
/home/main/lfs/3/root
$ 3/crosstools/bin/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -Wl,--verbose test.c 
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.26.20160125
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
   i386linux
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for -z combreloc: combine and sort reloc sections */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
          "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/tmptools/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      *(.rela.ldata .rela.ldata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.l.*)
      *(.rela.lbss .rela.lbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
      *(.rela.lrodata .rela.lrodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
      *(.rela.ifunc)
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rela.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
.plt.got        : { *(.plt.got) }
.plt.bnd        : { *(.plt.bnd) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table
  .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .gnu_extab   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gnu_extab*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges
  .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gnu_extab      : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gnu_extab) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata      : { *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*) }
  .tbss       : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array ))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array ))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 24 ? 24 : 0, .);
  .got.plt        : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  .lbss   :
  {
    *(.dynlbss)
    *(.lbss .lbss.* .gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
    *(LARGE_COMMON)
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  .lrodata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.lrodata .lrodata.* .gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
  }
  .ldata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.ldata .ldata.* .gnu.linkonce.l.*)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


==================================================
attempt to open crt1.o failed
attempt to open crti.o failed
attempt to open crtbegin.o failed
attempt to open /tmp/ccLVBgXQ.o succeeded
/tmp/ccLVBgXQ.o
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/usr/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib64/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib64/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /tmptools/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /tmptools/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/usr/lib/libc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/usr/lib/libc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib64/libc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib64/libc.a failed
attempt to open /tmptools/lib/libc.so failed
attempt to open /tmptools/lib/libc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/usr/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib64/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib64/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /tmptools/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /tmptools/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/main/lfs/3/root/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open crtend.o failed
attempt to open crtn.o failed
/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crtend.o: No such file or directory
/home/main/lfs/3/crosstools/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: perhaps `--with-lib-path` didn't do its job for some reason? try to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` manually.

Comment: If you mean setting it for the compilation command, that didn't change anything. I also thought that it only changed the dynamic library path at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

When I built a GCC toolchain for cross-compiling ARM, I used [this helpful tutorial](http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/).  The errors you are seeing look similar to what happens if you skip these commands:

```
make -j4 csu/subdir_lib
install csu/crt1.o csu/crti.o csu/crtn.o /opt/cross/aarch64-linux/lib
```

Which are part of a sequence of commands used to provide the headers for GLIBC to the cross-compiler.

```
mkdir -p build-glibc
cd build-glibc
../glibc-2.20/configure --prefix=/opt/cross/aarch64-linux --build=$MACHTYPE 
  --host=aarch64-linux --target=aarch64-linux \
  --with-headers=/opt/cross/aarch64-linux/include \ 
  --disable-multilib libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes
make install-bootstrap-headers=yes install-headers
make -j4 csu/subdir_lib
install csu/crt1.o csu/crti.o csu/crtn.o /opt/cross/aarch64-linux/lib \
  aarch64-linux-gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared -x c /dev/null -o \
  /opt/cross/aarch64-linux/lib/libc.so
touch /opt/cross/aarch64-linux/include/gnu/stubs.h
cd ..
```

It's unclear if the GLIBC headers are already in your sysroot directory, but I would start by checking to make sure those files exist. You may need to build the GLIBC headers if you are not getting them some other way.